# Increasing floating point precision in Python

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I was working on a project to compute the Leibniz approximation for pi with the below code:

```
def pi(precision):
    sign = True
    ret = 0
    for i in range(1,precision+1):
        odd = 2 * i - 1
        if sign:
            ret += 1.0 / odd
        else:
            ret -= 1.0 / odd
        sign = not sign
    return ret
```

However, the output value was always was 12 digits long. How can I increase the precision (e.g. more digits) of the calculation? Does Python support more precise floating points, or will I have to use some external library?

Comment: What a strange value for pi: ``>>> repr(pi(17))`` yields ``'0.8000913788523872'``

Comment: @alko Yes, this approximates one fourth of pi. see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80

Comment: What a strange method for pi evaluation, it converges **so slow**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `Decimal`.

Read [Arbitrary-precision elementary mathematical functions (Python)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150110065945/http://en.literateprograms.org/Arbitrary-precision_elementary_mathematical_functions_%28Python%29)<sup>[original](http://en.literateprograms.org/Arbitrary-precision_elementary_mathematical_functions_%28Python%29)</sup> for more information

Comment: Link is expired

Answer (score 6):

Python's `float` type maps to whatever your platform's C compiler calls a `double` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point_number).

The Python standard library also comes with an arbitrary-precision decimal module, called `decimal`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Answer (score 4):

The Leibniz formula converges extremely slowly - honestly, you won't live long enough for it get 12 digits of accuracy.  [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550135/pi-calculation-in-python) for one way to accelerate it enormously.

Answer (score 3):

With Python's float, you get 15–17 digits of precision (if you are seeing fewer, you may need to use a different format specifier when printing).

If you need more, you'll need to use a different method (one that only uses integer arithmetic), or a different way to represent floating-point numbers.

See [Python floating point arbitrary precision available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522933/python-floating-point-arbitrary-precision-available)

Comment: 12 is almost sertanly is raw print result, `float.__str__` trims up to 12 digits.