# Python truncate float with 19 chars

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm testing a simple validation program with some fields in float, but I have found a strange issue with these values. If chars are 18 python represents them as normal, at 19 chars, comprehensive of separator, python remove one decimal place, after switches in scientific notation:

This is what I have tried:

## 19 chars

```
>>> b = json.loads('{"a":  1000000000002222.22}')
>>> b
{'a': 1000000000002222.2}
```

## 18 chars

```
>>> b = json.loads('{"a":  100000000000222.22}')
>>> b
{'a': 100000000000222.22}
```

## 20 chars

```
>>> b = json.loads('{"a":  10000000000022222.22}')
>>> b
{'a': 1.0000000000022222e+16}
```

This is what I'm expecting:

## 19 chars

```
>>> b = json.loads('{"a":  1000000000002222.22}')
>>> b
{'a': 1000000000002222.22}
```

#OR#

```
{'a': 1.0000000000022222e+15}
```

## 18 chars

```
>>> b = json.loads('{"a":  100000000000222.22}')
>>> b
{'a': 100000000000222.22}
```

## 20 chars

```
>>> b = json.loads('{"a":  10000000000022222.22}')
>>> b
{'a': 1.0000000000022222e+16}
```

Comment: Floating point only has enough precision for about 17 digits.

Comment: With floating point double-precision values `10000000000022222.22 == 10000000000022222`

Comment: See also: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) and [Increasing floating point precision in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079282/increasing-floating-point-precision-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep arbitrary precision decimals when loading json numbers, then you must tell the `json` module to use a type that is capable of representing such numbers. Unfortunately `float` is suitable. However, both the `decimal` and `fractions` module can.

```py
import json, decimal
json.loads('{"a": 10000000000022222.22}', parse_float=decimal.Decimal)
```

gives:

```py
{'a': Decimal('10000000000022222.22')}
```

Maths with `Decimal` has its own set of caveats that are distinct from floats. Namely, *by default*, when the result of a mathematical operation cannot be fully expressed as a decimal (eg. `1/3`), then the number will be rounded to 28 significant digits. The precision of parsed strings is always exact.

```py
# 30 digits of precision
x = '1234567890.12345678901234567890'
d1 = decimal.Decimal(x)
print(d1) # d1 is exactly the number expressed by x
# outputs: 1234567890.12345678901234567890
d2 = d1 + 0
print(d2) # d2 has been rounded to 28 digits
# outputs: 1234567890.123456789012345679
```

If you need more precision, look at setting your own context or modifying the default one. eg.

```py
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
```

Or, if you need complete precision that is never rounded, then try using the `fractions` module.

```py
import json, fractions
json.loads('{"a": 10000000000022222.22}', parse_float=fractions.Fraction)
```

gives:

```py
{'a': Fraction(500000000001111111, 50)}  # NB. fraction has been normalised
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no mystery here. Two points:

1. - Converting `"1000000000002222.22"` (your first number) to an IEEE-754 single-precision float yields `0x58635fa9`; or `0x430C6BF526344572` as an IEEE-754 double precision float (the choice of using single- or double-precision is up to the Python implementation and can be inspected via [`sys.float_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info))
   - Converting `"1000000000002222.2"` (the number given back to you) yields ... `0x58635fa9` or `0x430C6BF526344572`. *It's the same number*.
     Floats are invariably approximation to their true underlying decimal representation. In fact, the extra `...2` at the end of the first number yields no benefit, as even the double-precision representation rounds that off.
2. [Since version 3.1](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.1.html#other-language-changes) (wayback in 2007) CPython uses the "shortest floating point representation that doesn’t change its value" for `float.__repr__`. That means CPython takes considerable effort to shorten all representations of the numbers you give **after conversion to float** has happened.

To drive the point home: Where did your extra decimal go? They were lost in the rounding that invariably happens when converting to a floating point number. The representation that you *see* is just a reflection of that fact.

Comment: The `decimal` module is good for seeing the exact decimal representation of `float` values

Comment: Note that Python hasn't guaranteed IEEE754 semantics until very recently, but in practice most systems have used double precision (i.e. binary64) floats.  MicroPython is the only implementation I know of that uses 32bit/single precision floats, seems unlikely op is using that unless it's explicitly mentioned

Comment: @SamMason "exact" in this context is typically about 28 places for `Decimal` rather than about 17 for `float`.